# PHP Role System - Logic Problems

Tags: php, mysql, roles

I'm developing a small project that I want to implement an "advanced" role system based on the page user visit.
I have some trouble in processing the logic behind this scheme, since I want to be able to add and remove roles and permissions, I think in this way to do it. Hope you can share your suggestions with me.

I have my users table that beside the username, password, etc fields, it contains a **userlevel** field.

I'm planning to create the following scheme:

Roles table:

```
id - AI -> is referenced with **userlevel** field in users table
name - Role Name 
description - Role Description Description
```

pages table:

```
id - AI
page_link -> saves the link of the page
description
```

permissions table:

```
id - AI
role_id -> referenced with **id** in roles table
page_id -> referenced with **id** in pages table
```

So my thought is:

Every page that is supposed to be protected in some way:

1. read the **userlevel** from users table;
2. Search if that role exists in **roles** table;
3. If not, deny access, if exists, create an array of **page_id** for the **role_id** from users permissions;
4. Create an array for **pages_link** from table pages based in the each **page_id** from table permissions;
5. Read the URL and if page link in array, allow access, if not, deny access;

I have my links like:
/add-user
/remove-user/**user_id**

If I give permissions to page /remove-user, can a user delete an user? (Basically access to /remove-user/**user_id**)

Am I thinking this the right way? I'm getting really confused in creating such system.
I would really like to have access to pages and features (for example, a moderador should be allowed to ban an user but not to delete it - if those features are on the same page, how can I achieve it?). Beside that I need another table for "functions" that allow the user do that or not and the create the code in the way?

For example table **userfunctions**

```
id
role_id
permission
```

If in this table there is a permission edit_users, then when rendering the page, if in array "feature", show or not button?

Can you kind please guide me in this way?
There is a quicker way to do this without such theory?
I can easily do this code, I'm just confused in the logic process behind a scheme like this.

Thanks

Comment: This is a rather broad question and likely not well-suited for SO, which is focused primarily on solving specific problems someone is having.  If you had built such a system and were getting an error or unexpected behavior from it, that's something that would probably garner some responses.  My advice would be to look into the popular frameworks that come with this type of functionality built-in so that you're not reinventing the wheel.  Authentication and authorization are not tasks to be taken lightly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Usually I don't use frameworks. I like to do it my own. Lets say I have my own microframework for my projects. Since its a logical question, I thought that could be fit here. This is not a problem to code, its a problem in the logic way. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

My personal approach:

1. Check if page is public (not restricted to any user), if so, stop.
2. Check if user is logged in, if not redirect to log in page.
3. Check if user's level is sufficient enough to view the page, if not redirect to their home page.

I usually do this by having at the top of each page one function to do all of the above:

```
<?php
require('system_loader.php');
check_access(ACCESS_LEVEL_ADMIN);
```

In my configuration files, I define a set of the current roles:

```
define('ACCESS_LEVEL_SUPERADMIN',1);
define('ACCESS_LEVEL_ADMIN',2);
define('ACCESS_LEVEL_MODERATOR',5);
define('ACCESS_LEVEL_USER',10);
define('ACCESS_LEVEL_PUBLIC',100);
```

This then allows me to at the top of each page define what access level is required to view it.

So, the pseudo-code for the function would be:

```
function check_access($level_required) {
 if ($level_required= ACCESS_LEVEL_PUBLIC) return;
 if (user_session_is_not_valid) redirect to login
 if (user_level < $level_required) redirect to user account page
}
```

This is a basic system, but it saves you from worrying about the logic, so long as you get everything in place in terms of managing the user session. It relies on a sliding scale of permission, such that the highest value will always have the most permission, and the lowest will have only public permission.

Mind you, having the roles hard coded in to the system is different that what you proposed in having the roles in the database. The same logic could be applied, except you would need to check the role in the database.

---

I should also note that your proposed system would work fine as well. It would be more complicated and would give far greater control in regards to individual functions and such.

In my example, you could simply restrict using conditional coding, checking if the user should be allowed to do a particular function.

If you expect to have roles not fitting in to a sliding scale of access, then you would indeed have to maintain a reference table linking the level of access with particular pages or functions.

Comment: Yeah, it's similar to my logic, but using a database to be fully dynamic. Thanks!

Comment: I just added a bit more, but yes, your proposed solution would work well. Your logic is sound.